# Solution to equations in 3 variable without forming a cubic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, cubics

Can we solve 3 equations:-
$$a+b+c = x$$
$$abc = y$$
$$ab+bc+ac = z$$
to get the value of $a,b$ and $c$
where $x,y,z$ are constants
As you can probably see I'm trying to find a solution to a cubic polynomial
I know other ways to solve the polynomial but I just want to see if we can find the solution using theses three equations

Comment: I don't think there's a way of solving an equation from the symmetries of the roots of the equation without finally getting down to the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *neither more nor less* than the cubic equation
$$ t^3 - xt^2 + zt - y = 0 $$
whose roots for $t$ are exactly your $a,b,c$. And every cubic equation can be transformed into this form.

If there were a known method of solving your nonlinear system of equations that were appreciably easier than Cardano's formula (for an exact solution with radicals), that method would be widely publicized as *the* good method for solving cubics. Since this hasn't happened, it is safe to assume that no such method is known.

Even if you're given the equation system *ab initio* and want just to find numerical *approximations* to $a,b,c$, the easiest method is probably to form the cubic and employ root-finding methods such as Newton-Raphson.